# WCF The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have these lines in my **web.config**:

```
<!-- Custom Bindings -->
<binding name="DETDESSOAP12Binding1">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
    <httpsTransport />
</binding>

<!-- Client -->
<endpoint address="https://wscourse.com/wsstack/services/R20.DETDESSOAP12Port/"
                   binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="DETDESSOAP12Binding1"
                   contract="Ws_Course.DETDESPort" name="DETDESSOAP12Port1" />
```

During tests everything went fine, but as soon as we published the project, we couldn't access the production URL because of the error `The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR)`.

I've googled the error message, accessed the production URL in the browser, checked the ?wsdl XML and everything looks fine, so what could be causing this? (and how do I fix it?)

I don't even know what end is causing this error (server or client) so any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Are you using plain WCF hosted in IIS or any other combination like Axis2? If plain WCF then are you able to browse to the service url from browser without any error?

Comment: @SivaGopal I don't know the server details (except that it's in Java), my service trying to access their is in WCF, and yes I can browse the URL without errors (aparently). I don't have the `.DETDESSOAP12Port` in the URL though, I just use `<url>/R20?wsdl`.